# Amazon EC2 with Amazon CloudFront prefix list security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Issue: I can only get HTTP code 200 server responses from my specific IP address (in this case, my home IP) despite having my EC2 security group allowing the Amazon CloudFront prefix list. I have a website in S3 distributed through CloudFront. I have a node server on EC2 that has an elastic IP configured. I have the following security groups

[image]

For obvious reasons, I've removed my home IP / security group for dev access from the screenshot. But this should allow my CloudFront to access my EC2? Or am I wrong in this approach?

CORS is enabled for the server to block requests not coming from the frontend production website. But I am not getting that error (because AWS steps in before it even gets there). The only way the server response to requests from other IP addresses is by having the security group inbound set to "open" for all IPs.

Am I wrong to think that the server should see the request coming from the frontend production website regardless of what IP address the user is at? Because it certainly feels like my IP address has a lot to do with the request being accepted versus the server just recognizing the request coming in from CloudFront. Thank you for any help. I apologize if this is a stupid/novice question. I've been looking around a lot for answers.

Comment: If you change the Inbound rule to permit access from anywhere (`0.0.0.0/0`) on port 443, does CloudFront work correctly? Also, it is normal to simply put an "Allow All" rule in the Outbound Rules rather than listing specific destination, since you can 'trust' the code running on the instance.